# Insert data into table

Tags: sql-server, python-2.7

I'm trying to insert array data into sql server table.

The table already defined and the connection works fine.

My current code is :

```
assets=[]
for asset in array:
if "some condition":
    assets.append(asset)


cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.executemany('insert into [Traffilog_Data].[dbo].[getData] values 
(%d,%d,%d,%s,%s,%f,%f,%d,%d,%d,%d,%s,%s,%f,%d,%s)', assets)
```

all %var are according to the sql table definition.

I' get result

```
None
```

same as simple select query

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well...do you get an error message? Also when performing inserts you should name all the columns. If your table adds a new column, your code will fail.

Comment: ProgrammingError: (102, "Incorrect syntax near 'd'.DB-Lib error message 20018, severity 15:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\n")

Comment: Well I don't know anything about python but that is not even close to valid sql server syntax. You can't pass an array and have sql server split it out for you. You have to provide each parameter individually. My guess is you need to pass each value and not "assets".